# ImageAndTextCell editing problem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I got ImageAndTextCell and I'm using it on a NSOutlineView. When I double click a cell in order to edit it, I get the following error:

2010-12-16 05:31:54.399 MyApp[26823:a0f] -[NSCFString representedObject]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0aff968

Does anyone know a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! Just remove the method

```
- (NSUInteger)hitTestForEvent:(NSEvent *)event inRect:(NSRect)cellFrame ofView:(NSView *)controlView
```